# Vuelidate 2 doesn't work properly with NuxtJS 2

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

I have installed vuelidate 2 to validate forms in my NuxtJS project. I followed instructions for installation and setup step by step according to [vuelidate documentation](https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/). This is how my setup files look until now:
package.json

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.2.2",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.22",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.5",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "uikit": "^3.7.1"
  }
```

plugins/composition-api.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

and nuxt.config.js for [@vue/composition-api](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api)

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/composition-api.js' }
]
```

and finally this is how I'm using vuelidate inside my component:

```js
<script>
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'
import { required } from '@vuelidate/validators'

export default {
  setup () {
    return { v$: useVuelidate() }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      contact: {
        name: ''
      }
    }
  },
  validations () {
    return {
      contact: {
        name: { required }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm () {
      this.v$.$validate()
        .then((isFormValid) => {
          if (isFormValid) {
            console.log('valid!!!')
          } else {
            return false
          }
        })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <label>
    <input v-model="contact.name">
    <div v-if="v$.contact.name.$error">Name is required.</div>
  </label>
</template>
```

These are a couple of problems that occur:

1. when I place `v-if="v$.contact.name.$error"` inside template I get the error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.
2. When I call submitForm method, the value of `isFormValid` is always false. Even when I have filled the `contact.name` field. And validation properties like `$dirty` don't change.
   I have no idea why these happen. What am I doing wrong?

Update: (In case it might be useful to solve the problen) My console errors filter was unchecked by accident and I hadn't seen this Nuxt warning: `[vue-composition-api] already installed. Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) should be called only once.`. As I searched about this error I found out Nuxt uses a dependency called `Nuxt composition api` which depends on `@vue/composition-api`. But when I reomved `@vue/composition-api` from plugins even the code inside `setup` didn't work correctly.

Comment: Hi, facing the same issue. How did you fix this?

Comment: @virajs0ni Hi, Couldn't fix this. I used vuelidate 0 instead.

Answer (score -1):

Solution with vuelidate:

create plugin (plugins/vuelidate.js):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

nuxt.config:

```
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vuelidate' }
  ],
```

import:

```
import { required } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
```

method:

```
formSubmit() {
      this.$v.$touch();
      if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
        // if invalid datas
      }
    },
```

template:

```
        <h3
          :class="{
            'is-invalid': $v.contact.name.$error,
          }"
        >
          Something
        </h3>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question is about vuelidate 2.

Comment: You need to ping @amirify for him to be notified of your comment.

Comment: He tried the vuelidate2 with the example?  @amirify

Comment: @MárkVarga No, the question is about vuelidate 2 which uses composition api plugin to be compatible with Vue 2. and your answer is not suitable for that. I have provided a link to vuelidate 2 docs. You can check getting started section.